# Hangfire Dashboard links point to wrong routes

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, hangfire

The problem is, when the app is deployed to a non root context (i.e. `http://root/someAppName/` the dashboard is by default accessible at `http://root/someAppName/hangfire`). 
But the dashboard lacks any js and css as they are being downloaded from the wrong locations. 
Same problem (with wrong location) happens with links. They all point to `http://root/someLinkName` skipping the `/someAppName` part of the context.
I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2.

There are similar questions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781570/hangfireui-wrong-urls-when-not-deployed-on-root) but it is unresolved and, in addition, doesn't refer to ASP.NET Core. How do I properly set-up my app to mitigate this problem? The app cannot be deployed to the root context and needs to stay under `/someAppName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue when an ASP.NET Core application with the Hangfire gets deployed behind a gateway or a load balancer. See [this](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1049), [this](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1110) and [this](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1368) for the reference. The workaround is to configure a gateway (load balancer) to pass `X-Forwarded-PathBase` to the application and add the following middleware before `app.UseHangfireDashboard()`:

```cs
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var pathBase = context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-PathBase"];
    if (pathBase != null)
        context.Request.PathBase = new PathString(pathBase);
    return next();
});

app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```