# Hangfire Dashboard broken after deployment - not load css and js

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, task, hangfire

**when working the development the dashboard is seen correctly, but when it is uploaded to production not load the css and js files**

project version net core 3.1 api

[hangfire error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GUZr.png)

my startup

```
            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new CustomAuthorizationFilter() }
        });
```

I tried the following without results, the server is windows and the authorization filter is simple... I'm not sure what the problem is... but it doesn't load the css and js files

```
            app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            // note : comment this to debug locally 
            context.Request.PathBase = "jobs";
            return next();
        });
```

Comment: Has it worked in production before?

Comment: yes but without authentication, the difference is that a querystring is used to authenticate in the CustomAuthorizationFilter

Comment: Please press F12, and check the link, we need to know which url was requested ?  And you also need tell us, did you use application gateway or load balance?

Comment: @GianL see this answer. It might be related to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606375/hangfire-dashboard-links-point-to-wrong-routes